# Why is every solution to the time-dependent Schrodinger eqn. of the form $\phi(x)T(t)$ or linear combination of functions of the form $\phi(x)T(t)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

$$i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(x,t)=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\partial(x,t)+U(x)\psi(x,t)$$

Why is every solution of the above equation either of the form $\phi(x)T(t)$ or a linear combination of functions of the form $\phi(x)T(t)$ i.e. $c_1\phi_1(x)T_1(t)+c_2\phi_2(x)T_2(t)+...$ ?

[This was actually claimed in "Introduction to Quantum Mechanics by David J. Griffiths",Chapter 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't, though physicists might pretend that it is.  If you add the important qualifications that $\psi(x,t)$ is square-integrable for fixed $t$, and that the Hamiltonian is self-adjoint, you need infinite series in the case of discrete spectrum, and integrals in the case of continuous spectrum.